# How can I perform multiplication in c?

Tags: c

I want to print multiplication of a number be n, till k times
like--n=4,k=5

```
n*n
n*n*n
n*n*n*n
n*n*n*n*n
```

I have tried this:-

```
int main()
{
    int i,j,k=5;
    for(i=1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", k*k);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can i do this to print the result? Thanks in advance

Comment: what about a loop.... like a for loop ....?

Comment: `for(i = 2; i <=k ; i++) printf("%d\n",pow(n,i))`

Comment: If you know how to accumulate, maybe you can tweak to do a multiplication.

Comment: @Madhurjya `printf("%d\n",pow(n,i))` That's using the wrong format for a floating point number. Plus, there is no need to mix floating point operations in an integer calculation.

Comment: Or may `k*=k; printf("%d\n",k)` inside the loop. You aren't really changing the value of `k`

Comment: `pow` could be my my own function not as provided as `math.h` I wrote it to give an idea of what the asker has to do in abstract. @dxiv

Comment: @Madhurjya Technically it *could* be, but that's a bad idea to suggest to someone learning the language.

Comment: @dxiv It is never a bad idea to push a learner, provided he is eager to think, learn and debug.

Comment: I was trying to implement it but i was stucked at some point .. thank you guys@Madhurjya and @dxiv for ur help

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```c
    int n = 5;
    int k = 5;
    int result = n;

    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
        result *= n;
        printf("result = %d\n", result);
    }
```

Output is:

> result = 25
>   result = 125
>   result = 625
>   result = 3125